# Using my php scripts in Android to access database

Tags: php, android

I need some major help in setting up my android app to add/receive data to/from my database. I'm using Amazon's RDS service in connection with xampp's phpMyAdmin. I've already successfully connected my DB instance to the database in phpMyAdmin. Also, I've written my php scripts to do basic CRUD (Create, Read, Update, Delete) commands in SQL. I've been following [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/) tutorial.

The problem for me is, in his tutorial he is using strings like this:

```
private static String url_all_products = "http://api.androidhive.info/android_connect/get_all_products.php";
```

to run his php scripts in a call to `makeHttpRequest(url_all_products)`. But I don't have my own website to do this and I'm pretty sure I don't need one to do this.

Next, I have a `test.php` file that does a simple `echo` statement and it works when I run this in a web browser:

```
http://localhost/phpfiles/test.php
```

Which leads me to my second problem. I don't want to use `localhost` because I need these php files and the ability to retrieve data from the database to be accessible to anyone using my app. This is the sole reason I'm using Amazon's RDS service so my database can be accessed on the cloud.

So how can I use the host address provided to me by Amazon RDS to access the database and *where* do I store all the php files so I can properly use them in Android the way the tutorial shows? They are currently saved in `xampp/htdocs/phpfiles/`.

I feel like I'm missing some fundamental understanding of all this and I'm going about it all wrong. If someone can point me in the right direction that would make my day.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you don't really need the XAMPP install on your local machine at all. You're hosting this on Amazon and you want it to be available to the internet, so your local computer isn't involved. You can use XAMPP locally for testing and development, but for production use you'll be exclusively on the Amazon RDS cloud.

> But I don't have my own website to do this and I'm pretty sure I don't need one to do this.

You may not want a **website**, but you *do* want your services hosted on the internet. That's what your RDS instance is for, and technically the tutorial is referring to an API which happens to be exposed through a web page. This is a much better idea than opening MySQL directly to the internet on port 3306.

You'll then use your Amazon host — for which you really should use a FQDN such as `api.example.com` rather than the IP address, but the IP address will work just fine from a technical aspect.

The files you refer to are on your local XAMPP installation; in the `xampp/htdocs/phpfiles/` folder, and need to instead be on the RDS instance.

Then your application accesses the API you expose in those files which return information back to your application.